# JS > bind HTML onclick event to a Custom Element v1 object

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, bind, custom-element

*TL;DR*

How can I bind the callback of an inline onclick-event of a div element to the Custom Element, in which the div is placed?
I want to use `onclick="foo('bar')"` instead of `onclick="this.foo('bar')"`.

*Long version*:

Having appended an **Custom Element** with a **clickable div** to DOM as follows:

```
<my-element>
    <!-- 1. works  -->
    <div onclick="this.foo('bar')">click me</div>

    <!-- 2. not working -->
    <div onclick="foo('bar')">click me</div>

    <!-- edit: 3. playground (works) -->
    <div onclick="me.foo('bar')">click me</div>
</my-element>
```

... now I want to bind the `foo()`-function to my Custom Element (`<my-element>`).

**1st solution**: Here `onclick` calls a `foo()`-function on `this` (`this.foo()`), where `this` later gets bound to my Custom Element (see following code).

**2nd solution**: Here I want to omit `this.` and again bind it to my Custom Element. But: while the binding works in the above solution (1.), it does not without a prepended `this.` - that's my problem.

**edited 3rd solution**: Uses a Proxy to project the function call from `me` to `this` Custom Element. It doesn't solve the problem, but at least I tried.

So the problem is: How to get solution 2 working?

My Custom Element v1 class - including some code I tried:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
    }

    connectedCallback()
    {
        var self = this

        this.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, true)

        // Proxy for solution 3
        window.me = new Proxy({}, 
        {
            get: function(target, prop) 
            {
                return self[prop]
            }
        })
    }

    handleClick(ev)
    {
        console.log(ev.target.onclick)
            // returns: ƒ onclick(event) { foo("bar") }
            // > is typeof function

        // provides the binding to "this" for solution 1
        ev.target.onclick = ev.target.onclick.bind(this)

        // call
        ev.target.onclick()
            // works on first solution
            // throws error in 2nd solution: foo is not defined
    }

    foo(str)
    {
        console.log(str)
    }
}

customElements.define('my-element, MyElement)
```

Some explanations:

- Using `addEventListener` and setting its 3rd parameter (`useCapture`) to true, I capture the event before getting executed.
- I'm able to log the `foo()`-function to the console. It is encapsulated in a callable function, which seems to be the reason, why I can't bind my context to the `foo()`-function itself.
- Calling the function via `ev.target.onclick()` throws an error, as in the given context (`window`) no `foo()`-function exists.

Some thoughts:

- **React** does something similar (I haven't used React yet), but I can't see  how to transfer their solution, as they eventually somehow preprocess their onclick events (with eval?). That might be a reason why their syntax is `onclick={foo}` instead of `onclick="foo()"`. I also don't know, if passing parameters is possible in React.
  See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html
- Referring to that, it might be a problem, that in my solution the `foo()` function is probably already somehow called inside the window context, what means, that it's context is already set and can't be changed anymore...? Anyways, trying to set `onclick="foo"` without brackets and calling it later  doesn't work either.

Good read to this topic:

http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

So, I don't know if there is a solution at all. Ideas or explanations are welcome anyways!

EDIT 2: Fixed.

It also works, when the element is created and appended from inside the element class:

```
var el = document.createElement('div')
el.innerHTML = 'click me'
el.onclick = () => {
    this.foo('bar')
}
this.appendChild(el)
```

EDIT 3, 4, 5:
Played around a little (see solution 3) and assigned a Proxy object to a global variable ('me'), which projects any function calls to `this` Custom Element - kinda `__noSuchMethod__`. So... by choosing a 1- or 2-character-variable one could save at least a few hits on his keyboard by not typing `this.` but `me.`, `vm.` or even `i.` ... best solution so far. Sad!
Unfortunately, solution 3 can also not be used as general pattern for all elements, as it bounds the context only to one (i.e. the last connected) Custom Element.

---

EDIT 6 - Preliminary conclusions

As it turns out, it seems not possible to bind a html-inline onclick-event (`onclick="foo('bar')"`) to the Custom Element class, in which the clickable element is embedded.

So the most obvious ways to go to me would be:

A) use the this keyword (like `onclick="this.foo('bar')"`) and bind it to the class as shown above. Why `this.foo()` is bindable whereas `foo()` without `this` is not, remains unclear at the moment. I wonder bc both functions do not really differ - both have already bindings: `this.foo(`) is bound to the clickable element, `foo()` is bound to `window`.

B) use eval as suggested by @Supersharp, i.e. add an event listener to the Custom Element, listen for clicks, get the value of the onclick-attribute as string, prepend "this." to  the string and effectively do this: `eval("this." + "foo()")`.

C) alternatively to inline onclick, I would tend to use event delegation and use declarative html attributes to indicate behaviour. To do this, again add a click event listener to the Custom Element class:

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {

        if (ev.target.dataset.action)
        {
            this[ev.target.dataset.action]()
        }

    }, false)
```

Your clickable element would look like `<div data-action="next">Show more</div>`.

Comment: why don't you want to use the *orthodox* way: `this.parentElement.foo('bar')`? this don't require any extra javascript handler.

Comment: parentElement would return the parent dom element, but I need the Custom Element (= its class) in which the clicked element is embedded.

Comment: the parent Dom element *is* the custom element actually. you could also invoke it by its id.

Comment: in my example, yes. but in more complex cases mostly not. would be possible to use a function to recursively walk up the dom with parentElement and find it. but I better like an easy implementation with less code. my goal was to bind a "foo()" without a prepended "this" to a class.so if thats not possible I'll stay with "this." or listen to events on attributes like "[action=openMenu]".

Comment: then  call the custom element by it id. see my updated answer.

Comment: named elements. convenient :) but too fiddly imo. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use `eval()` on the concatenation of `"this."` and the content of the `onclick` attribute the `event.target` element.

Don't forget to use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop dispatching the event.

```
handleClick( ev )
{
    eval( 'this.' + ev.target.getAttribute( 'onclick' ) )

    ev.stopPropagation()
}
```

If you don't want to use `eval()`, you should parse the content of `ev.target.getAttribute( 'onclick' )` to extract the function name et arguments and then call the element method if it exists:

```
if ( typeof this.name === 'function ) 
    this[name](arguments)
```

**Update**

I suggest that you give an `id` to the custom element, then call the id + method:

```
<my-element id="me">
    <div onclick="me.foo('bar')">click me</div>
</my-element>
```

This way you don't need to redirect/catch the event, and the `div` can be anywhere in the element.

Comment: thank you. indeed I wanted to avoid eval. parsing seems to be the only opportunity. think I'm gonna stay with using this.

Comment: yes parsing is the only alternative. If you don't want to use eval then you should avoid to use inline script (i.e. onclick="foo()') as this kind of syntax is evaluated by the browser too.